# Solving an $n$ system of equations via using Matrices *by the book!*

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> **Question:** How do you find the unknowns to a system via Matrices without a calculator?

I have been reading a book, and it introduced a way to solve an $n$ linear equation with $n$ variables.

> The equations and the values of the variables are arranged below:
>   $$\begin{align*} & a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\ldots+a_nx_n=\xi_1,\qquad &  x_1\Delta=A_1\xi_1+B_1\xi_2+\ldots+L_1\xi_n\\ & b_1x_1+b_2x_2+\ldots+b_nx_n=\xi_2,\qquad &  x_2\Delta=A_2\xi_1+B_2\xi_2+\ldots+L_2\xi_n\\ & \ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\qquad & \ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\\ & l_1x_1+l_2x_2+\ldots+l_nx_n=\xi_n,\qquad & x_n\Delta=A_n\xi_1+B_n\xi_2+\ldots+L_2\xi_n\end{align*}$$
>
> Where $\Delta$ is the determinant annexed, and $A_1,B_1,\&c$ are its first minors.$$\begin{bmatrix}a_1\ldots a_n\\\ldots\ldots\\ l_1\ldots l_n\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> To find the value of one of the unknowns $x_r$; *Multiply the equations respectively by the minors of the $r^{\text{th}}$ column, and add the results. $x_r$ will be equal to the fraction whose numerator is the determinant $\Delta$, with its $r^{\text{th}}$ column replaced by $\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3\ldots\xi_n$ and whose denominator is $\Delta$ itself.*

A handful!

I'm confused by what to do. What do they mean by "minors", the $r^{\text{th}}$ column, and "determinant annexed"? This seems like a fast way to solve a large system, but I can't figure it out.

I've tried rereading and breaking it down; but no matter what, I still can't get it. Perhaps you guys can help provide some insight on what this means for me!

Comment: No, for large systems this is anything but fast, because of the necessity of computing determinants of order $n$, which means at least $n!$ order of magnitude for the computational complexity!

Comment: @AlexM. Oh... I still want to learn this method though...

Comment: It is explained here ... http://www.math.cornell.edu/~andreim/Lec17.pdf